# How to make DIV's width equal to 1 of 2 preset values depending on content length?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have dynamically generated content into DIVs and need DIVs widths to get adjusted depending on the content in the DIV **by two preset values**.

It should work like this: if we have a long content - the width should be = **960px**, if there is a very few contents - just **480px**.

So only two values and only two variations of the width: 960px or 480px.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.page-list-img {
  clear: both;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 5px !important;
  opacity: 1.0;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
}

.page-list-img:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
}

.button-page-list-p {
  text-align: left;
}

span.lister {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;
}

.page_list_container {
  width: 960px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.column2 table {
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 130px;
}

.column2 table td {
  border-style: none !important;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.column1 {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 130px;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  height: 130px;
}

.column2 {
  border-left: solid 0.7px #ddd;
  text-align: justify;
  /*line-height: 130px;*/
  float: initial;
  /* width: 789px; */
  padding-left: 10px;
  height: 130px;
  display: table;
}

.row-lister {
  min-inline-size: 460px;
  max-inline-size: 100%;
  /*float: left;*/
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  border-top: solid 0.7px #ddd;
  border-bottom: solid 0.7px #ddd;
  border-left: solid 0.7px #ddd;
  border-right: solid 0.7px #ddd;
  /*width: 940px;*/
  /* width:460px; */
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="page_list_container">
  <div class="row-lister">
    <div class="column1">
      <span class="lister"><img class="page-list-img" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/shararam-smeshi/images/1/1c/CSS.png/revision/latest?cb=20161102175256&path-prefix=ru" /></span>
    </div>
    <div class="column2">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h4>Title</h4>
              <em>Description here</em>
              <p class="button-page-list-p"><a href="" title="Bone fixation devices">Find out more</a></p>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-lister">
    <div class="column1">
      <span class="lister">
               <img class="page-list-img" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/shararam-smeshi/images/1/1c/CSS.png/revision/latest?cb=20161102175256&path-prefix=ru"  />
            </span>
    </div>
    <div class="column2">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h4>Title</h4>
              <em>Description here</em>
              <p class="button-page-list-p"><a href="" title="Bone fixation devices">Find out more</a></p>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-lister">
    <div class="column1">
      <span class="lister">
               <img class="page-list-img" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/shararam-smeshi/images/1/1c/CSS.png/revision/latest?cb=20161102175256&path-prefix=ru"  />
            </span>
    </div>
    <div class="column2">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h4>Title</h4>
              <em>Long description here Long description here Long description here Long description here Long description here Long description here Long description here Long description here Long description here Long description here Long description here Long description here Long description here Long description here Long description here Long description here Long description here Long description here Long description here Long description here Long description here</em>
              <p class="button-page-list-p"><a href="" title="Bone fixation devices">Find out more</a></p>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-lister">
    <div class="column1">
      <span class="lister">
               <img class="page-list-img" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/shararam-smeshi/images/1/1c/CSS.png/revision/latest?cb=20161102175256&path-prefix=ru"  />
            </span>
    </div>
    <div class="column2">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h4>Title</h4>
              <em>Description here</em>
              <p class="button-page-list-p"><a href="" title="Bone fixation devices">Find out more</a></p>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-lister">
    <div class="column1">
      <span class="lister">
               <img class="page-list-img" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/shararam-smeshi/images/1/1c/CSS.png/revision/latest?cb=20161102175256&path-prefix=ru" />
            </span>
    </div>
    <div class="column2">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h4>Title</h4>
              <em>Description here..... This is also a bit longer</em>
              <p class="button-page-list-p"><a href="" title="Bone fixation devices">Find out more</a></p>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-lister">
    <div class="column1">
      <span class="lister">
              <img class="page-list-img" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/shararam-smeshi/images/1/1c/CSS.png/revision/latest?cb=20161102175256&path-prefix=ru" />
           </span>
    </div>
    <div class="column2">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h4>Title</h4>
              <em>Description here longer a bit ...</em>
              <p class="button-page-list-p"><a href="" title="Bone fixation devices">Find out more</a></p>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-lister">
    <div class="column1">
      <span class="lister">
              <img class="page-list-img" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/shararam-smeshi/images/1/1c/CSS.png/revision/latest?cb=20161102175256&path-prefix=ru" />
           </span>
    </div>
    <div class="column2">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h4>Title</h4>
              <em>Description here</em>
              <p class="button-page-list-p"><a href="" title="Bone fixation devices">Find out more</a></p>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-lister">
    <div class="column1">
      <span class="lister">
              <img class="page-list-img" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/shararam-smeshi/images/1/1c/CSS.png/revision/latest?cb=20161102175256&path-prefix=ru" />
           </span>
    </div>
    <div class="column2">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h4>Title</h4>
              <em>Description here</em>
              <p class="button-page-list-p"><a href="" title="Bone fixation devices">Find out more</a></p>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the last DIV in the page (**even** if it has a small content, but it is left **only one** in the **last row**) it's width has to be set to **960px** anyway.

I was said to use flex for this purpose. But it solves only the sole DIV in the last row and content-depending width of the DIV. But, if you have many DIVs with different amount of contents in them you have different sizes of the DIVs, however rows will be filled by 100%.

**EDIT**

**I have a table in the DIV with the content**, so it could be useful to determine the length of the content (as we cannot predict the size of the content, as it can consist of images and text of different styles).

I am looking for CSS or jQuery.

Thank you!

Comment: Jquery will solve this. Pliss add some code or what you have tried so i can help you.

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO Hello! Thank you. I have updated my post.

Comment: "if we have a long content". What is long. We need to set a value for a long or not long enough text

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO this is a problem. I understand it, but, if we have sometimes images, sometimes texts in different styles, that cannot be predicted... what would you suggest?

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO In my DIV with content there is a table with one TD. We can measure it (to determine whether the content is "long" or not?)

Comment: I would recommend a view port scale. 50% of the screens width.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the problem is.  Wouldn't this work? https://jsfiddle.net/se70y7dq/

Comment: @JosephMarikle Hi! Can you check the updated snippet (right from the real example (instead of text and image, sure)) )

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO Can you check the updated snippet (right from the real example (instead of text and image, sure)) )

Answer (score 0):

You can use max-width and a dynamic unit as `%`. To limit the space any conent or element can use, depending on the parrent element.

In this case use :

```
.row-lister {
    max-width: 49%;
 }
```

This will limit each element to 49% of it parent `.page_list_container`.
I used 49% because you have margins between each element. I would recommend you to set does margins in `%` so they all add up to 100%.

Hope this helps :)

```css
* {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .page-list-img {
        clear: both;
        width: 100px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        vertical-align: middle;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        padding: 5px !important;
        opacity: 1.0;
        transition: opacity 500ms;
    }
    .page-list-img:hover {
        opacity: 0.5;
        transition: opacity 500ms;
    }
    .button-page-list-p {
        text-align: left;
    }
    span.lister {
    display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        line-height: normal;

    }
    .page_list_container {
        width: 960px;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }
    .column2 table {
        border: none;
        width: 100%;
        height: 130px;
    }
    .column2 table td {
        border-style: none !important;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .column1 {
     text-align: center;
        line-height: 130px;
        float: left;
        width: 150px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        height: 130px;
    }
    .column2 {
        border-left: solid 0.7px #ddd;
     text-align: justify;
        /*line-height: 130px;*/
        float: initial;
        /* width: 789px; */
        padding-left: 10px;
        height: 130px;
        display: table;
    }
    .row-lister {
        min-inline-size: 460px;
        max-inline-size: 100%;
        max-width: 49%;
        /*float: left;*/
        border-radius: 2px;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        border-top: solid 0.7px #ddd;
        border-bottom: solid 0.7px #ddd;
        border-left: solid 0.7px #ddd;
        border-right: solid 0.7px #ddd;
        /*width: 940px;*/
        /* width:460px; */
        margin-right: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="page_list_container">
<div class="row-lister">
<div class="column1"><span class="lister"><img class="page-list-img" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/shararam-smeshi/images/1/1c/CSS.png/revision/latest?cb=20161102175256&path-prefix=ru" /></span></div>
<div class="column2">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<h4>Title</h4>
<em>Description here</em>
<p class="button-page-list-p"><a  href="" title="Bone fixation devices">Find out more</a></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row-lister">
<div class="column1"><span class="lister"><img class="page-list-img" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/shararam-smeshi/images/1/1c/CSS.png/revision/latest?cb=20161102175256&path-prefix=ru"  /></span></div>
<div class="column2">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<h4>Title</h4>
<em>Description here</em>
<p class="button-page-list-p"><a  href="" title="Bone fixation devices">Find out more</a></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row-lister">
<div class="column1"><span class="lister"><img class="page-list-img" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/shararam-smeshi/images/1/1c/CSS.png/revision/latest?cb=20161102175256&path-prefix=ru"  /></span></div>
<div class="column2">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<h4>Title</h4>
<em>Long description here Long description here Long description here Long description here Long description here Long description here Long description here Long description here Long description here Long description here Long description here Long description here Long description here Long description here Long description here Long description here Long description here Long description here Long description here Long description here Long description here </em>
<p class="button-page-list-p"><a  href="" title="Bone fixation devices">Find out more</a></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row-lister">
<div class="column1"><span class="lister"><img class="page-list-img" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/shararam-smeshi/images/1/1c/CSS.png/revision/latest?cb=20161102175256&path-prefix=ru"  /></span></div>
<div class="column2">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<h4>Title</h4>
<em>Description here</em>
<p class="button-page-list-p"><a  href="" title="Bone fixation devices">Find out more</a></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row-lister">
<div class="column1"><span class="lister"><img class="page-list-img" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/shararam-smeshi/images/1/1c/CSS.png/revision/latest?cb=20161102175256&path-prefix=ru" /></span></div>
<div class="column2">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<h4>Title</h4>
<em>Description here..... This is also a bit longer</em>
<p class="button-page-list-p"><a  href="" title="Bone fixation devices">Find out more</a></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row-lister">
<div class="column1"><span class="lister"><img class="page-list-img" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/shararam-smeshi/images/1/1c/CSS.png/revision/latest?cb=20161102175256&path-prefix=ru" /></span></div>
<div class="column2">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<h4>Title</h4>
<em>Description here longer a bit ...</em>
<p class="button-page-list-p"><a  href="" title="Bone fixation devices">Find out more</a></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row-lister">
<div class="column1"><span class="lister"><img class="page-list-img" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/shararam-smeshi/images/1/1c/CSS.png/revision/latest?cb=20161102175256&path-prefix=ru" /></span></div>
<div class="column2">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<h4>Title</h4>
<em>Description here</em>
<p class="button-page-list-p"><a  href="" title="Bone fixation devices">Find out more</a></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row-lister">
<div class="column1"><span class="lister"><img class="page-list-img" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/shararam-smeshi/images/1/1c/CSS.png/revision/latest?cb=20161102175256&path-prefix=ru" /></span></div>
<div class="column2">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<h4>Title</h4>
<em>Description here</em>
<p class="button-page-list-p"><a  href="" title="Bone fixation devices">Find out more</a></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Dear @Gerardo, thank you. This one is quite obvious answer.. but.. your post with LONG contents became all the same 49%. In my original listing (if you run it) you will see, that long contents make divs full length (960px) which is GREAT and I need to keep it. But the others I need to get whether 960px or 480px. Not 485px, not 470px etc. Just two variants. But when my snippet works the rest (small contant divs) became different in width.. ((